# Remove space before macro if exist a environment

Tags: macros, floats, line-breaking

I create a new macro:

```
\newcommand{\intersection}[1]{%
\par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\noindent\textbf{\large\bfseries\sffamily #1}\par}
```

It works perfectly for what I want, but when there is a environment before macro, latex insert two lines:

[image: extra-space]

If possible that macro "detects" when exist a figure (or other environments) don't insert a line break?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\intersection}[1]{%
\addvspace{\baselineskip}%
\noindent\textbf{\large\bfseries\sffamily #1}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{image.pdf}
\caption{\textbf{a)} En la situación normal...}
\end{figure}

\intersection{Ion-dipolo}
La ley de Coulomb explica las \textbf{\textit{fuerzas ion-dipolo}}, las cuales atraen entre sí a un ion (ya sea un catión o un anión) y a una molécula polar. La intensidad de esta interacción depende de la carga y tamaño del ion así como de la magnitud del momento dipolar y del tamaño de la molécula.

\intersection{Ion-dipolo inducido}
Se dice que el dipolo del átomo (o molécula no polar) es un dipolo inducido porque la separación de sus cargas positiva y negativa se debe a la proximidad de un ion o una molécula polar. La interacción atractiva entre un ion y el dipolo inducido se conoce como interacción \textbf{\textit{ion-dipolo inducido}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\addvspace` not `\vspace`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Why?

Comment: Because addvspace is designed to do exactly what you ask, it looks at the space (if any) just added, and then adds the maximum of the space already there and the space in the argument so you don't get a double space. (If your question had had an example document I would have posted the result of the command:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Would this also work around floats (it's a very specific location) and their `\belowcaptionskip` / `\floatsep` / `\intextsep` spaces?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Sorry, I update my question. I replace `\vspace` but nothing happen.

Comment: @Werner no, it tests the space on the main vertical list, but actually floats should not be a problem as they are (in the main) at a page break so the space will have been discarded anyway at the break

Comment: ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `SLightBlue'.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I update the code. The color font is not important for this question ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `\addvspace` rather than `\vspace` then the space will combine with space for *in text* environments such as `center` or `quote`. However your space here is coming from a float. Normally floats are top or bottom of a page, in which case the space before your heading would be discarded at the page break. The extra space here is coming because it is an `h` float. The simplest thing to do is reduce the space around h floats either globally, or just before the heading, for example

```
\setlength\intextsep{2pt}
```

The default in article class is 6pt.

Comment: I think of other possibility. Is it possible do something like `if else` like other programming languages to decide when use a `\intextsep`?

Comment: @Kiyoshi intextsep is always used, it is inserted at the point latex decides to position the float as a here float rather than top or bottom float, so you can not test within the page